# The usage of 一本 vs 一杯。

Tags: adjectives

So for 一本、we know that 本 is a measure word for long cylindrical objects in class. If you were to order a glass of sake, you would use （お酒の名前）一本ください。My question is when can you use 一杯 for sake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In alcohol contexts, 本 is the counter for bottles and [とっくり (sake bottles)](https://search.yahoo.co.jp/image/search?ei=UTF-8&fr=sfp_as&aq=-1&oq=&ts=892&p=%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8A&meta=vc%3D), which are usually cylindrical. If the restaurant serves sake poured in a tokkuri along with an ochoko, you can order saying 1本ください. In an izakaya that serves sake in a glass or a cup, you should use 1杯. In both cases, saying ひとつ is always okay, too.

The same goes for ordering beer or wine; 1本 refers to a whole bottle, 1杯 refers to a glass.